# Can Blender be programmed to visualize cash?

Tags: animation

Can Blender can be programmed to illustrate cash for financial investments. For example, one of my investments is worth this today

[image: Cash Value]

but that value changes from day to day. Would blender be able to make YouTube videos or not. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Please do not ask closed questions (questions where no/yes would be the answer) Also do not put two different questions in a single question. Also as this seems to be a python question. what have you tried, and where did you get stuck. Also in this specific case where does the data come from.

Comment: @J.Bakker Well I would consider a "Can something be done?" to be meant as "How can something be done?" even if it has not much info in it - I consider the 'How' silent, but generally it is true the best is to be explicit to avoid this..:)

Comment: Please edit the question and include more details what you are after, so we can better help you how to achieve that. After editing the question may be re-opened.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not getting back for about 24 hours, I just now got an email. What my goal is, is to setup Blender to understand the difference in value from a penny all the way upto a $100 bill. The human mind tends to be better at understanding money for investments or debt on seeing cash instead of just seeing a bank statement. That is my goal. I am not aware of programs that do this. I have been searching on Google without really finding an answer. @J. Bakker thanks for the heads up. I'm just starting out with Blender. I just started watching Blender Guru on YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

The question is whether Python, the programming language used in Blender, can get the data. If Python can get it, either through a text file or from online sources or manual input, then it's perfectly possible to change graphs and swap texts and change more or less anything on the screen according to the data.

```
import bpy
# changing a text
textName = 'Text' # name of the text object
value = 500.0 # value to be displayed
txt = bpy.data.objects[textName].data.body = str(value) # replacing the text in the text object

# changing the length of an object in order to make a graph
objName = 'Cube' # bar that is supposed to change length
value = 80 # which value does the bar have to represent
bpy.data.objects[objName].scale.z = value / 10 # setting the scale of the bar.
```

When a bar graph is done like in the script above, it's helpful to put the object origin at the bottom of the bars. That way the scale won't destroy the bottom alignment.

[image]

If you want to visualize money with coins and bills, that's possible, too. You can change the position and the visibility of any object:

```
import bpy

bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location.x = 3.0

bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide = 1
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide_render = 1
```

It's simply a matter of hiding, revealing and arranging.

Comment: Hi. please see my reply to Pierre Schiller "Sorry for the confusion. I do not want a graph. If I did, I could use Excel. I want a way to actually show cash. For example, when I asked the question yesterday, my investment was worth $820.12 and today it's crept upto $820.66 I would want the program to understand the difference by being able to show 8 $100 bills, 1 $20 bill 2 quarters (50) cents a dime, a nickel and a penny. That is what I'm looking for. I would guess this has to be rendered. Thanks"

Comment: The right place for this detail is in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you´d like to do a hub. Otherwise simple animating the scale with reference values on a chart on the side and down would be sufficient. No?
Hub like ->Read data from php/mysql->Write values on a table (text), Blenderaddon.py picks it up and the rest gets represented on Blender. But what puzzles me it's the fact you'd like this to be rendered? Then you´d also need command line... 
Like the first answer said: this is too broad subject.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do not want a graph. If I did, I could use Excel. I want a way to actually show cash. For example, when I asked the question yesterday, my investment was worth $820.12 and today it's crept upto $820.66 I would want the program to understand the difference by being able to show 8 $100 bills, 1 $20 bill 2 quarters (50) cents a dime, a nickel and a penny. That is what I'm looking for. I would guess this has to be rendered. Thanks

Comment: The right place for this detail is in your question.

Comment: @Nicholas He's saying you need to add this info to your question by clicking edit and not make it a comment.